# Go to an specific URL ionic React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

When an IonIcon is pressed I need load an specific URL.
The only thing I have been able to find is using

this.props.history.push('/')

But what I need to do is go home. How is it possible to do it?

```
const Ingresar: React.FC = () => {

    const goBack = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/')
        };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar>
        <IonGrid>
          <IonRow>
          <IonCol><IonIcon icon={arrowBack} onClick={goBack} slot="start" id="flecha-volver">  </IonIcon></IonCol>
          <IonCol id="columna2" ><strong id="texto-pagina">Registro de usuario</strong></IonCol>
          </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
      </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IngresarDatos></IngresarDatos>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't access `this` in functional component

Comment: Thanks @Nisharg. How can I go to an specific URL with a IonIcon click event?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `this` in `functional component`

```
const Ingresar: React.FC = props => {

    const goBack = () => {
        props.history.push('/')
    };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar>
        <IonGrid>
          <IonRow>
          <IonCol><IonIcon icon={arrowBack} onClick={goBack} slot="start" id="flecha-volver">  </IonIcon></IonCol>
          <IonCol id="columna2" ><strong id="texto-pagina">Registro de usuario</strong></IonCol>
          </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
      </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IngresarDatos></IngresarDatos>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Nisharg. How can I go to an specific URL with a IonIcon click event?

Comment: enter the url of that component here `.push('/<HERE>')`

Comment: props.history.push('/home') give me an error: Cannot find name 'props'.ts(2304)

Comment: Please specified the props in first line, like `cont Ingresar: React.FC = props => {...}`

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!